# Macro to select sheets in a dynamic list (Named) containing all the sheets' names

Tags: validation, macros

My workbook has sheets named from A to Z and a Master-sheet with values auto-populated from sheets A-Z. A dynamic list on Mastersheet updates itself based on which sheets have values greater than Zero. That dynamic list only has the letters A,B,C - Z (excludes tabs which have total value of "0")

I would like a macro able to select only the sheets in that dynamic validation list. The list is named "PdfPrintOfTabsWithData".

Would someone be so kind to let me have a macro that selects sheets based on info on a named list?

Best

AKAKAK

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve the problem yourself? I assume this question is about excel?

Comment: Apologies, Yes Excel question. Tried to do it myself but couldnt do it. Any ideas?